# SpringMVC: URL parameter after query parameters

Tags: spring, forms, spring-mvc, get, action

I have an HTML form in which I'd like to have additional URL parameters *after* the form query.
For example, the URI I'd like to end up with may look like this:

```
/publications?pub_type=article&year=2016/titles
```

However, I don't know how to write the `action` of the HTML form for this. Is it possible?

```
<form method="get" action="/publications [?] /titles ">
...
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this:

In form action

```html
action="/publications/pubTypeVal/yearVal/titles"
```

And server-side

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "publications/{pubTypeVal}/{yearVal}/titles", method=RequestMethod.GET)

public String hello(@PathVariable("pubTypeVal") String pubTypeVal, @PathVariable("yearVal") String yearVal) {
// your implementation
}
```